# rank over shredded xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sqlxml

Given the following sample of XML and the `select` statement that shreds the xml into a relation, what **I need is the second column of the `select` to be the ordinal of the category** (ie 1 for the directions and 2 for the colours in this case).

Note: The literal value 'rank()' in the select is left a placeholder. I was poking around with using the `rank`, but with no success.

```
declare @x xml
set @x = '
    <root>
        <category>
            <item value="north"/>
            <item value="south"/>
            <item value="east"/>
            <item value="west"/>
        </category>
        <category>
            <item value="red"/>
            <item value="green"/>
            <item value="blue"/>
        </category>
    </root>'

select c.value('./@value', 'varchar(10)') as "ItemValue", 
       'rank()' as "CategoryNumber"
from @x.nodes('//item') as t(c)
```

Comment: If only I could work out how to use "fn:id"... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190915.aspx

Comment: @marc_s --unfortunately the xml is what it is --- I can't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jacob Sebastian also has an interesting solution presented in his blog post:

[XQuery Lab 23 - Retrieving values and position of elements](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2008/08/21/xquery-lab-23-retrieving-values-and-position-of-elements.aspx)

With Jacob's suggestion, I can rewrite your query to be:

```
SELECT
    x.value('@value','VARCHAR(10)') AS 'ItemValue',        
    p.number as 'CategoryNumber'
FROM
    master..spt_values p
CROSS APPLY 
    @x.nodes('/root/category[position()=sql:column("number")]/item') n(x) 
WHERE
    p.type = 'p'
```

and I get the desired output:

```
ItemValue   CategoryNumber
---------   --------------
north           1
south           1
east            1
west            1
red             2
green           2
blue            2
```

Unfortunately, none of the more obvious solutions like the `position()` or `fn:id()` functions seem to a) work in SQL Server or b) be supported in SQL Server at all :-(

Hope this helps

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this: you get first element of each category and use it as an id.

This:

```
select c.value('./@value', 'varchar(10)') as "ItemValue", 
    c.value('../item[1]/@value', 'varchar(10)') as "CategoryNumber"
from @x.nodes('//item') as t(c)
```

Returns:

```
Item Value | CategoryNumber
---------------------------
north      | north
south      | north
east       | north
west       | north
red        | red
green      | red
blue       | red
```

And then just

```
select c.value('./@value', 'varchar(10)') as "ItemValue", 
   RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c.value('../item[1]/@value', 'varchar(10)')) as "CategoryNumber"
from @x.nodes('//item') as t(c)
```

It however returns:

```
Item Value | CategoryNumber
---------------------------
north      | 1
south      | 1
east       | 1
west       | 1
red        | 5
green      | 5
blue       | 5
```

But it is still step ahead.

Comment: As it turns out this will work just fine.  I need to have the output grouped by category with some arbitrary value, but it doesn't have to be contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `position()` to produce output (why??), but you can use it as XPath filters:

```
 with numbers (n) as (
  select 1
  union all select 2
  union all select 3
  union all select 4
  union all select 5)
 select i.x.value('@value', 'varchar(10)') as [ItemValue],
    n.n as [rank]
  from numbers n
  cross apply @x.nodes('/root/category[position()=sql:column("n.n")]') as c(x)
  cross apply c.x.nodes('item') as i(x);
```

You can use a real numbers table for higher ranks. For very large number of categories in a single document is not going to be efficient, but for moderate numbers (tens, hundreds) will work just fine.

Comment: I'm glad you figured this out; I was trying to come up with something similar, but failing miserably.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Lukasz answer, I was able achieve the desired result with:

```
SELECT
  I.Item_Instance.value('@value','VARCHAR(10)') AS Item_Value,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C.Category_Instance) AS Category_Ordinal  
FROM @x.nodes('/root') AS R(Root_Instance)
CROSS APPLY R.Root_Instance.nodes('category') AS C(Category_Instance)
CROSS APPLY C.Category_Instance.nodes('item') AS I(Item_Instance);
```

It returns:

```
Item_Value Category_Ordinal
---------- --------------------
north      1
south      1
east       1
west       1
red        2
green      2
blue       2
```